# Updating related records in EF core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update a record and it's related entities but I'm struggling to find a way that it will work.

I have a entity that store information about school governors and their ethnic origin. The ethnic origin entity is a simple lookup table.

When I try to update the record without anything specific it doesn't update the ethnic origin, or if I specifically try to update it it fails with this error message...

"The property 'Id' on entity type 'EthnicOrigin' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal."

However, I can't remove the dependent as it is the record I need to update.

This is the code..

```
public bool UpdateGovernor(Governor updatedGovernor, User user)
    {
        try
        {
            Governor myGovernor = _ctx.Governors
                                    .Where(u => u.Id == updatedGovernor.Id)
                                    .Include(i => i.EthnicOrigin)
                                    .Include(u => u.Tenant)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

            if (myGovernor.Tenant.Id == user.Tenant.Id)
            {

                _ctx.Entry(myGovernor).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedGovernor);
                _ctx.Entry(myGovernor).State = EntityState.Modified;

                _ctx.Entry(myGovernor.EthnicOrigin).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedGovernor.EthnicOrigin);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                string error = "Tenant breach" + Environment.NewLine;
                error += "User :" + user.emailAddress.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                error += "Updated Governor :" + updatedGovernor.Id.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

                _logger.LogError($"Failed to update governor: {error}");
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to update governor: {ex}");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the exception message looks like `myGovernor.EthnicOrigin.Id` is different from `updatedGovernor.EthnicOrigin.Id`. If that's true, you need to handle that case differently. Sample model and [mcve] will help getting more concrete answers.

Comment: turns out I'd missed the EthnicOriginID from the governors entity.         public EthnicOrigin EthnicOrigin { get; set; }
public int EthnicOriginID { get; set; }  <<<this one